# Where to store image,in database or server folder

Tags: database, web-applications, file-upload, web, scalability

I am building an application,in which user will upload lots of pics.What should be the best way to store all pic on web.
I mean to say I should store in database or server folders.Which will be more scalable and fast.
If it is data base, Which database.
Please suggest me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to store the images in the folder structure, because it is easier to download and do some changes (image quality / optimize) and then put back to server.

Without any interaction with database (for security reason about database structure or data) it is easy to do operations on image as per your / client needs.

More flexibility if you run out of storage space (move them to another disk), even use them in other apps